# Update array from variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the 'path' to an array value stored in a variable, and I am trying to set the value. What I am trying to do is this:

```
$array['Breaks'][1]['In'] = "XXX";
```

However, I have `['Breaks'][1]['In']` stored in a variable. So I am essentially trying to do something like this:

```
$path = "['Breaks'][1]['In']";
$array.$path = "XXX";
```

This doesn't work though, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about making this work correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to parse `$path` and then cycle through the parsed values to set the value.

Comment: Why do you have `['Breaks'][1]['In']` in a variable? Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I am using AJAX to dynamically update values in a large array. It POSTs the data, and this is POSTed to my update script to be able to select and modify the data.

Comment: Uhhu. And why do you have `['Breaks'][1]['In']` in a variable again?

Comment: ... so my script can update that value?

Comment: But why are you using that string? How does it get in there. Can't you use JSON, XML, separated variables or whatever else is better suited?

Comment: The application was already scripted this way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to re-write the whole application, just a way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this,

```
//This solution works if you are sure the length of $path_arr is going to be 3
$path = "['Breaks'][1]['In']";
$path_arr = explode(']', str_replace(array("['", "'", "["), '', $path)); 

$array[$path_arr[0]][$path_arr[1]][$path_arr[2]] = "XXX";
var_dump($array);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/EswThZsV)

Comment: Thank you! Simple, and works, just as I asked. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the path string is not modifiable by users or parsed through previously you could just do:

```
eval("\$array".$path." = 'Value';");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting each component of the $path variable into its own variable, or into an array ($pathArray below). So, if you had $pathArray[0] set to 'Breaks', $pathArray[1] set to 1, etc., you could do something like:

```
$array[$pathArray[0]][$[pathArray[1]][$[pathArray[2]] = "XXX";
```

Although this seems like an unusual way to go about things, and it might be worth re-thinking your approach entirely.